# sed command to delete a line matching a pattern is not working in my case

Tags: awk, sed

These are the contents of my file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0:

```
192.168.1.12/32 via 172.16.1.60
192.168.1.0/24 via 172.16.60.1
```

I am deleting a line using the follwing sed command:

```
sed  -i  '#192.168.1.0/24 via 172.16.60.1#d'   /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0
```

But the matching line(line 2 in our case) is not getting deleted. Any insights?

**Note:** I am using #(hash symbol) as seperator in sed command because /(forward slash symbol) is part of my pattern.

Comment: Make sure to accept an answer that's either using a string comparison (e.g. in awk via `index()` or `==` or `grep -Fx`), or if it's doing a regexp comparison is escaping every `.` to `\.` and using  `^` and `$` delimiters to avoid deleting the wrong line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gnu sed supports REGEX pattern as address. You can use any delimiter you like, just like `s` (substitution)

You can do :

```
sed '\%pat%d'
sed '\#pat#d'
sed '\@pat@d'
```

That is, you just escape the first `#` in your code, your command will work.

Answer (score 3):

If escaping `/` chars in the expression is a problem, you might use `awk`:

```
awk -v search='192.168.1.0/24 via 172.16.60.1' '$0 != search' file > file.tmp \
&& mv file.tmp file
```

or inplace with `gawk`:

```
gawk -i inplace -v search='192.168.1.0/24 via 172.16.60.1' '$0 != search' file
```

Comment: `Using a delimiter different than / is only supported by the s` it is wrong.

Comment: yeah, looks like. I've learned something, thanks. Also thanks to @potong for the edit!

Comment: PS: I feel a bit ashamed to receive 3 up for an initially wrong answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
grep -v '192\.168\.1\.0/24 via 172\.16\.60\.1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '!/192\.168\.1\.0\/24 via 172\.16\.60\.1/' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed: replace first `#` with `\#`.